# Command Line Tools Not Available

Tags: macos, command-line-tool

I attempted to install Apple's Command Line Tools via Terminal (xcode-select --install). Halfway through the installation, it fails and a popup window says: "Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server." This problem is on Apple's end, right? If not, how do I go about installing the Command Line Tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an Apple failure, or it could be a network failure on your part. Try opening the software update in the app store and see if it can contact the update server. If it fails to contact the update server, I would say this is a problem with Apple. If that doesn't fail to contact the server, you may want to look into it being a potential network problem on your side.

In order for us to tell you another way to install it, we need to know what version of OSX you're on. The new XCode for Mavericks doesn't have it in the downloads section like the old XCode used to have. In fact, I have it installed for `brew` and don't see it in the list of downloads in XCode.

Comment: I'm on OSX 10.9.1. I don't think it's a problem on my side.

Comment: I actually don't think Command Line Tools for 10.9.1 exists yet. I just tried manually downloading it via developer.apple.com with my dev license and there is no listing for CLT for 10.9.1. How long do you think that will take Apple?

Comment: There is CLT for 10.9.1. I had to install it when I went from 10.8 to 10.9. I downloaded mine from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?=command%20line%20tools.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why I deleted this question a couple months ago. I think that I thought it was a different question that I needed to delete. I just happened across it and it said that it was deleted. I'm dumbfounded why I might have done that. I truly apologize for that. I awarded you with the answer. Again, I'm very sorry and confused.